# JTextField not showing String passed to it from a variable

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In the code below `JTextField` is not displaying string passed to it, but if l use sysout to display the variable its working.

```
public void setTableData(FormEvent ev) {
    System.out.println(ev.getCustomerID()); //working
    customerIdField.setText( ev.getCustomerName()); // not show anything
}
```

Comment: Seems `ev.getCustomerID()` and `ev.getCustomerName()` can return different result.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: yes they return different results but my challenge is if l  do this  customerIdField.setText(ev.getCustomerID()); its not showing anythig  only

Comment: System.out.println(ev.getCustomerID());  is displaying results in the console

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting text to your desired textfield ?  Otherwise you code should work smooth as you said your getCustomerID() prints desired value with sysout ..